# How to access embedded documents in MongoTemplate when the key is an empty string?

Tags: mongodb, mongotemplate

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("550add7ee0b4b54a3e7ad53c"),
        "day" : "14-03-2015",
        "node" : "2G",
        "nodeName" : "BLR_SGSN",
        "" : {
                "A" : 905.84,
                "B" : 261.34,
                "C" : 2103.94,
                "D" : 39.67
        }
}
```

I have this as my data in mongo.
How do I get values of A,B,C,D. ??

Comment: Ouch! does your data really look like this of have you typed it incorrectly. The blank key there `""` looks more like a programming error to me.

Comment: Yes!! ..unfortunately Data is same. an Empty Key.

Comment: You will never be able to .`find()` this so will fixing it suffice as a rework of your question? Or do you just want some silly bug report that does not fix anything?

Comment: So am I. It seems a horrible thing I have never seen before. You can set a property to `""` but renaming this is a problem. At least efficiently. Give me a moment.

Comment: What's the expected result? Do you want the values in an array?

Comment: I am able to do with Key, but without key i am unable...@chridam  : yes

Comment: try this normal query `db.collection.find({},{".A":1})`

Comment: @yogesh Are you reading the comments above? That cannot work

Comment: @user3561036 above given query work for me also `db.collection.distinct("")` and `db.collection.distinct(".A")` also works tested with mongo version `3.0.3`

Comment: @yogesh .. i am looking For MongoTemplate  solutions

Comment: @user3561036 I don't think this is bug it works with mongo version `3.0.3` I already mentioned above also in your answer I tested this `db.collection.find({ ".A": 1 })` this also return me whole matching documents.

Comment: @user3561036 this is not good idea to set key name as `""` but we can get nested values of using `""` this key, and **bug**  and naming conventions both are different things.

Comment: @yogesh It's a bug and be done with it. If someone wants to delete this statement then contact me directly to discuss.

Comment: See [SERVER-2051](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-2051). In addition, according to the [BSON specs](http://bsonspec.org/spec.html), an empty string is a valid _element name_. But very probably a bad idea though.

Comment: @SylvainLeroux It's a **very** bad idea and bound to break in various language mechanics

Comment: @SylvainLeroux If you want to add a "relevant" issue from a task to be resolved then I am all for it. But issue `2051` is sequential and ostensibly "open" the current issue count is `19049` as of the time of writing. That's 17000 issues raised in between that point and this coming up. So yes, lots of issues that are not relevant get raised on systems. But generally issue reports that are several years old and not resolved are never going to be resolved. Therefore this is not useful information to people. I'd love to see a nice answer to a question from you.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot query on this as the sub-document fields cannot be selected.

This can only be a result of a programming error doing something like this ( and probably trying to compute a key name in the process ):

```js
db.collection.insert({
    "": {
        "A": 1,
        "B": 2,
        "C": 3
    }    
})
```

So you cannot get to sub-elements by standard query ways like:

```js
db.collection.find({ ".A": 905.84 })
```

You can fix this by updating the documents in the collection affected in this way by giving them a proper key name. But it is of course this is an iterative process. Not sure how to fix this other than with JavaScript from the shell due to the naming problem but:

```js
db.collection.find({ "": { "$exists": true } }).forEach(function(doc) { 
    if ( doc.hasOwnProperty("") ) { 
        doc.newprop = doc[""]; 
       delete doc[""]; 
       db.collection.update({ "_id": doc._id }, doc );
    }
})
```

Then at least you can access things by the new "newprop" key ( or whatever you call it ):

```js
db.collection.find({ "newprop.A": 905.84 })
```

And the same sort of thing will work in other drivers.

My advice here is "go and fix this" and find out the code that caused this key name to be `blank` in the first place.

There should be a bug report submitted to the MongoDB core project as none of the dirvers handle this well. I thought I could even use [**`$rename`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/rename/) here, but you can't.

So blank `""` keys are a problem that needs to be fixed.